# MongoDB GridFS Python download_to_stream_by_name throws 'unicode' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

When using the PyMongo driver for MongoDB, I'm able to upload images to GridFS successfully using bucket.upload_from_stream(filename, address). It's very straightforward and has no complications.
But when I try to retrieve that same data using `bucket.download_to_stream_by_name(filename, address)`, with the second parameter as destination, it throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Why is this happening? How do I set the location I want to save my files at?

Comment: @Rawing I did read the documentation multiple times, but there's absolutely no clarification on what the file-like object should be. The file-like object, as it seems to be in the documentation example, does not provide any opportunity to specify the storage location, even though the parameter is called 'destination'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of using download_to_stream_by_name and creating a file in a directory on your disk:

```
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient
from gridfs import GridFSBucket

my_db = MongoClient().test
fs = GridFSBucket(my_db)
file_id = fs.upload_from_stream(
    "test_file",
    "data I want to store!",
    chunk_size_bytes=4,
    metadata={"contentType": "text/plain"})

fs = GridFSBucket(my_db)
# Get file to write to
if not os.path.exists('my_directory'):
    os.makedirs('my_directory')

file = open('my_directory/myfile','wb')
fs.download_to_stream_by_name("test_file", file)
```

A "file-like object" is one that has a "write" method that takes chunks of characters to write. An actual file object created by the "open" function is one possibility of a file-like object.

Note, the filename passed to download_to_stream_by_name is the filename in GridFS, not a filename on your disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @A. Jesse Jirya Davis, but my issue is not exactly downloading, but rather specifying the download directory. I can specify the download directory in Node.js, but I'm unable to configure it in this.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to create a directory.

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis do you know how I can specify the bucketname in cmd:
fs = GridFSBucket(my_db) ?